# Как профессионально расти в программировании?

Tags: c++, linux, c, windows

Вот я читал в одной книге, что для того, чтобы научиться программировать, нужно отложить книги и начинать читать чужой исходный код. Но код, иногда, читается так сложно, даже программы с gnu сайта. Может есть какие-нибудь программы, которые и мыслей добавят, и чему-нибудь научат?

Мне, иногда, очень сложно становится, что хочется податься в веб разработку. Но тогда придётся учить и php ( который я немного знаю ), и javascript ( который тоже знаю ), и html и css. То что можно заработать на веб разработке на фрилансе. А на си так просто не заработать. Нужно быть профессионалом, а как?

Откуда сетевые программисты знают, что надо писать в программе? В вузах что ли учат этому, инженеров наверное каких-нибудь? Я хочу стать профессионалом и писать на си, ну и, может быть, на c++ ( так как время от времени его читаю ).

Да, и почему у хороших программистов такой сложный код, и казалось бы простая программа, а так много кода написано, это я про gnu утилиты.

Comment: Идите работать. Там вы увидите много чужого кода (если проэкт большой).

Comment: Меня не возьмут на работу программистом. У меня образования нет.

Comment: "_Мне, иногда, очень сложно становится, что хочется податься в веб разработку_". А вы думаете там проще ? Хотя конечно если писать ширпотреб, где время открытия страницы по 5 секунд, то наверное проще (писать). "_Я хочу стать профессионалом и писать на си_", вообще профессионал тот, кто может в любой момент писать на любом языке, который оказался наиболее подходящим для решения конкретной задачи. потому что язык - не более чем инструмент.

Comment: так и хочется в коммент от @Mike подставить "..., а вообще можно и отвёрткой гвозди заколачивать." :)

Comment: @Mike, прямо таки на любом языке в любой момент? Это где-нибудь в Нарнии такие программисты живут?

Comment: "Я хочу писать на си" это не правильная поставновка вопроса. Наверное правильнее будет "я хочу разрабатывать игры, прикладной софт, драйвера, решать задачи... " т.е. си это просто инструмент. Если вы хотите писать игры, а компания пишет драйвера - то вам будет скучно.

Comment: Пишите программы, любые. Калькуляторы, крестики-нолики, всё, что угодно. Когда напишете несколько, тогда и может появится смысл в чтении чужого кода, но просто так читать нет смысла. Большая часть кода откровенный шлак, вне зависимости от того, опен сорс это или нет. К примеру, libstdc++ это реализация стандартной библиотеки для GCC — это просто кошмарный сборник кода, читать который можно вместо просмотра фильмов ужасов. Лучше всего найти работу, конечно, потому что там Вам будут давать задачи. А без работы задачи себе выставлять придётся самому.

Comment: @Mike,  я с вами категорически не соглашусь.  Есть профессиональные очень хорошие программисты, которые умеют писать только на С++, ну может чуточку знакомы с другим языком тоже, но они пишут исключительно на C++.  Также человек может быть профессиональным инженером—механиком, но не  знать электронику

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Если профи и пишет только на одном языке, то если его завтра поросят на чем то другом, он скорее всего ответ "да не вопрос", потому что большинство имперических языков очень похожи. Главное все таки понимание машины и умение составления алгоритма, а на чем его выразить дело десятое. Понятно, что без глубоко знания библиотек незнакомого языка большая вероятность велосипедостроения, но программа все равно будет сделана и заработает

Comment: @Mike, это уже другой разговор, но  под профессионализмом обычно понимается ; человек делает это каждый день у себя на работе, и на этом зарабатывает  успешно. Все просто- определение это правильно для любой специальности...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> чтобы научиться программировать, нужно отложить книги и начинать
>   читать чужой исходный код.

Ну да... А для того, что бы научиться хорошо играть в футбол - надо смотреть все матчи по телевизору! А что бы заработать кучу денег надо день и ночь смотреть на портрет Дж. Сороса :-)

Единственный способ научиться что-то делать - это делать это что-то САМОМУ! Изучение чужого кода может Вам *помочь* понять какие-то тонкости кодирования. Но основные принципы можно освоить только занимаясь практической работой.

Если под словом "программирование" понимать процесс создания программ/системм, то он состоит из двух основнх компонент:

- Проектирование
- Кодирование

Процесс проектирования имеет первостепенное значение и важнее кодирования в десятки раз. Хотя по затратам времени так и не кажется. Но, если проект программы сделан качественно, то закодировать его может даже самый начинающий кодировщик. А если проект отвратительный, то даже очень опытный кодировщик может запутаться.

Проектирование - процесс постепенного разбиения сложной задачи на более простые и так далее. Не буду рекомендовать какие-то конкретные книги (ну, кроме может быть Д. Йодан "Структурное проектирование и конструирование программ"), но рекомендую сосредоточиться именно на этом. А тонкости использования конкретных языков вроде того, как правильно надо отступы расставлять - дело десятое!

> Меня не возьмут на работу программистом. У меня образования нет

Вот этим летом, у меня на глазах, развивалась такая история:

Молодй мужчина (около 30 лет), всю жизнь проработавший пожарником (с дипломом гражданского ВУЗа)  и осознавший дальнейший тупик, уволился, поступил в магистратуру на программирование и одновременно нашёл работу в софтверной компании. Пока он на испытательном сроке, но магистртатуру он заканчивает на одни "5" год за два и испытательный срок тоже скоро кончится. Но даже сейчас он получает значительно больше, чем получал как командир пожарного расчёта. Так что - не сдавайтесь!